# SharePoint delegation for powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, chart

[image: Delegation warning.]
How to control the delegation to avoid the warning? It is limited to my subscribe 365 account.

Comment: This is more of a Power Apps question. Plus did you read about it first? There's a video series dedicated for it and tons of resources explaining this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this delegation warning possibly because you are using a [supported delegable function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview#delegable-functions) in one of the formulas on the chart, where some of other functions cannot be delegated to any data source.

The only way you can get rid of the warning sign is to adjust your formula and use only supported delegable functions. But it can be safely ignored as long as the table contains fewer than 500 records.

Answer (score 2):

The following [Microsoft Article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/delegation-overview) explains about delegation pretty thoroughly.

The delegation warning is not something that is linked to your type of account or your subscription but is rather due to the functions used to access the underlying datasets or perhaps the datasets themselves.

Keep in mind the delegation warning only applies if you are accessing datasets that return more than 500 rows (By default, this can be adjusted to between 1 and 2000) So if you have the warning but you have a small dataset you can probably ignore the warning.

You are receiving the warning because you are potentially accessing a data set that is not one of the following (Sourced from the above article):

- Common Data Service
- SharePoint
- SQL Server

Or potentially because you are using one of the following non delegable functions (Sourced from the above article):

- First, FirstN, Last, LastN
- Choices
- Concat
- Collect, ClearCollect
- CountIf, RemoveIf, UpdateIf
- GroupBy, Ungroup

To remove the warning you may need to revisit your formula and see if you can use the delegable Datasets and/or functions.